# Python - how to extract a soap envelope from input xml and send as output

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python and I have an input xml which has a soap envelope embedded in it under a child node.
Input xml:

```
    <SyncShipmentCreation  xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="2">
        <ApplicationArea>       
           <CreationDateTime>2022-06-22T14:21:56Z</CreationDateTime>        
         </ApplicationArea>
        <DataArea>
           <Sync>
            <TenantID>TLD_TST</TenantID>            
           </Sync>
           <ShipmentCreation>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soapenv:Header>                    
                </soapenv:Header>
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <ShipmentRequest xmlns="http://xxxyyyzzz.com/ShipmentMsgRequest">
                        ...
                    </ShipmentRequest>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </ShipmentCreation>
    </DataArea>
</SyncShipmentCreation>
```

The soap part is the Output needed. Like

```
         <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                       ..............
            </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is this possible? I could not find how to parse/extract this value and assign to an output variable. Please help.

Comment: Try looking at [Intro to XPath with Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath).

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of doing it is by using the lxml library in the following way:

```
from lxml import etree

soap ="""[your xml above]"""

doc1 = etree.XML(soap)
#locate your target nodes and assign them to a second document
doc2 = doc1.xpath('//*[local-name()="ShipmentCreation"]/*')[0]
print(etree.tostring(doc2).decode())
```

The output should be your expected output.